# Adding a library to classpath for all ANT tasks

Tags: java, ant, javac

I need to add a library that becomes by default available to all ANT tasks. Is this possible without changing my ANT script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, by placing the jar in your $ANT_HOME/lib directory.